# How to authenticate for https://management.azure.com api?

Tags: azure, powershell

I want to retrieve data on my DNS zones through a API call:

```
$api = "?api-version=2018-05-01"

$pat = "Bearer $env:System_AccessToken"

Write-Host "### PAT ###"
Write-Host $pat

$DNSInformation = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/$zoneName/$recordType/$relativeRecordSetName$api"

Write-Host "###"
Write-Host $DNSInformation
Write-Host "###"

$x = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $DNSInformation -Headers @{Authorization = $pat } -Method Get
```

When I run this script I get:

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

When I navigate to the URL I get:

```
error: {
    code: "AuthenticationFailed",
    message: "Authentication failed. The Authorization header is missing."
}
```

I think the issue is that I can't use the `$env:System_AccessToken` token to get on the `management api`. But I can't find information what kind of authentication is needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Powershell to check resource names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35306082/azure-powershell-to-check-resource-names)

Comment: Hm might be a duplicate question.

Comment: Using $env:System_AccessToken looks like you're doing this in Azure DevOps (formerly VSTS) are you running this from there or is this a value you've set locally?

Comment: I'm running the code in a pipeline.

Comment: A pipeline in Azure DevOps? The System_AccessToken in Azure DevOps is for the Project Collection Build Service principal. Therefore meaning that this credential is authenticated against Azure DevOps for your convenience not Azure Management api. To do what you need to do the answer posted above will do it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

As the error mentions, the authorization header is incorrect.

```
$URI = "https://management.azure.com/providers/microsoft.resources/checkresourcename?api-version=2014-01-01"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Method GET -Headers $authHeader
```

You can use a couple of approaches to create your header:

1. As you mentioned - [Azure Powershell to check resource names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35306082/azure-powershell-to-check-resource-names)
2. By creating Bearer token : [Powershell Script to delete unused resources in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56260695/powershell-script-to-delete-unused-resources-in-azure)